# How to set up local ede project

Tags: emacs

I am using Emacs 25.1 on windows.

I learnt using auto-complete, ede-mode from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTUE03LnaXA) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ib914gNr0ys&t=6s).

I have following code in init.el and using ede project mode

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Active semantic                      ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(require 'cc-mode)
(require 'semantic)
(global-semanticdb-minor-mode 1)
; turn on automatic reparsing of open buffers in semantic
(global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode 1)
; turn on Semantic
(semantic-mode 1)
; let's define a function which adds semantic as a suggestion backend to auto complete
; and hook this function to c-mode-common-hook
(defun my:add-semantic-to-autocomplete() 
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-semantic)
)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my:add-semantic-to-autocomplete)
; turn on ede mode 
(global-ede-mode 1)
; create a project for our program.
(ede-cpp-root-project "my project" :file "D:/Work/Learning/Emacs/my_program/src/main.cpp"
              :include-path '("../" "../my_inc"))
```

It works. My question is can I have ede project setting as a local variable, so that I do not need to set all my projects in one place `init.el`.

If I can do this, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `ede-cpp-root-project` when you open a source code file :

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
  (lambda () (interactive) (ede-cpp-root-project "my project" :file (buffer-file-name)
              :include-path '("../" "../my_inc")))
```

Or instead of `(buffer-file-name)`, some function of it that gives you a corresponding root.

Comment: Is it possible to put your comment in a file under my project root folder, so that I do not need to input them every time when I open my source code file?